# Call post function when dropdown selected change in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was  Bind one dropdown  with some values and call my post action when dropdown selected changed   .for look like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DistrictId, Model.DistrictList, "Select", new
       {
           disableValidation = "true",
           onchange = @"
            var form = document.forms[0]; 
            form.action='Index';
            form.submit();"
       })
```

This is working fine for call my controller post action . But I can't get  dropdown selected value in my model DistrictId property .

For my controller function is look like below

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HomeModel homeModel)
        {
            AdminController adminController = new AdminController();
            Guid userId = new Guid();
            homeModel.ComplianceModelList = complianceRepository.LoadComplianceModel(userId, homeModel.DistrictId);
            LoadDistrict(homeModel);
            return View(homeModel);
        }
```

I want to the dropdown selected DistrictId in my homeModel.DistrictId property .

How to do ?

Comment: Are you sure `document.forms[0]` is the form that has the DistrictId field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got the solution

Below code was working good .

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <h2 class="gridTitle">
            Compliance</h2>
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
        {
        <div class="complianceSubDiv">
            <div class="complianceRightDiv">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.DistrictId)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DistrictId, Model.DistrictList, "Select", new
           {
               disableValidation = "true",
               onchange = @"                        
                form.submit();"
           })</div>
        </div>
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your Markup like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DistrictId, Model.DistrictList, "Select")
```

and have some javascript to handle your change event so that it will serialize your form and send it to your action method using ajax.

```
$(function(){
  $("#DistrictId").change(function(e){
    var _this=$(this);

    $.post("@Url.Action("Index","Home")",_this.closest("form").serialize(),
                                                             function(response){
          // do something with response.
    });
  });
});
```

Assuming you have jQuery library loaded to your page.

Comment: No .It does not call the action .for reason of .Where  i give the dropdown id Id in use of this  $("#DistrictId")

Comment: Check your HTML markup and see what ID is there for the dropdown and use that.

Comment: THANKS MAN. there are a lot of examples around that dont work. Your example does!